# Sudden IE8 load() problem

Tags: jquery

Suddenly this week my IE8 users started complaining that certain `load()` requests were not loading correctly. No change in code, and just with IE8 - FireFox 3 & 4, Chrome latest and IE9 RC all work fine.

Here is the code:

```
$("#"+div).empty().html('<center><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></center>');
$("#"+div).load(url);
```

We load a 'loading' gif (which IE8 users see just fine), and then load the url into the div.  IE8 users don't get any errors, they just get a blank screen. The loading gif goes away and there is nothing in the `div`. `url` does have a random # attached to avoid caching, and the funny thing is `load()` is working just fine for them in other spots of the app.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be some bad `<script>` code on the page that was working fine in every browser except IE8 (was fine in IE7 and IE9 too). I removed the `<script>` and the rest of the page worked just fine.

I used [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to test all the IE versions. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the server script you are calling sends proper HTML and it doesn't throw any errors. Also you may try like this:

```
// To prevent the need of manually adding random #
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$('#' + div)
    .html(
        $('<center/>', {
            html: $('<img/>', {
                src: 'ajax-loader.gif',
                alt: 'loading...'
            })   
        })
    )
    .load('/foo');
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mrd5u/5/) (working under IE8).